# MS Azure lab missing some information

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-oms

In `Experience D - Working with a Service Map` of the official Azure lab titled `Introducing Azure Management Solutions` they are asking to follow the following steps. But, as shown in the image below, I'm not getting `ServiceMap(SWMIAAS-OMS):` in the search result. What I may be missing?

In the left menu of Azure Portal: Click on Monitor-->Log Analytics-->Log Search, then:

1. In the Search resources box near the top of the screen, type servicemap
2. In the search results, click ServiceMap(SWMIAAS-OMS)
3. On the ServiceMap(SWMIAAS-OMS) solution blade, click the Service Map tile
4. In the Machines list on the left, click non-swmiaas-vm1

Screen Shot of Log Search blade [You can click on the image for better readability:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I test in my lab.

> In the Search resources box near the top of the screen, type
>   servicemap

You should do as below:

[image]